# How do you change a one dimensional list into two dimensional using existing elements?

Tags: python

I am reading in a text file containing several lists with each on its own line. The elements in a given list are non-integer x,y co-ordinates that need to be placed into an array such that:

> [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,....xn, yn]

becomes:

> x1 x2 x3....xn
>
> y1 y2 y3....yn

but in the same 2d array.

I'm very new to coding and have tried various methods but to no avail. Right now I am looping over the number of co-ordinate pairs and trying to append the values within the loop but am unsure how to do this.

This is how I have started it:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        array=[]
        number=(line.count(" ")+1)/2 #number of x,y pairs in list
        for i in range(0, number-1):
```

Now I don't know where to go from here so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to python and you are dealing with numerical data, you may want to consider the *de facto* standard module for such manipulations, [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/). With it, your problem becomes trivial:

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print np.array(A).reshape((len(A)/2,2)).T

>>> [[1 3 5 7]
     [2 4 6 8]]
```

Here we cast the list in to a numpy array `np.array`, `reshape` it into the size we desire and take the transpose `T` to get from `(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...` to `(x1,x2,...),(y1,y2,...)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use list slicing with `2` as its steps :

```
>>> l=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3']
>>> l[0::2]
['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
>>> l[1::2]
['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
```

Or you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and go throw your list with `next()` :

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> l=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3']
>>> c=cycle(l)

>>> l1=[]
>>> l2=[]
>>> for i in range(len(l)/2):
...  l1.append(c.next())
...  l2.append(c.next())
... 
>>> l1
['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
>>> l2
['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list like

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

you can do

```
b = [a[0:len(a)-1:2], a[1:len(a):2]]
```

which will return a list containing two lists (kind of 2D python array)

```
>>> [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

This actually works if you are sure the length of your array is even.

Comment: Make it `b = [a[0::2], a[1::2]]` and it will work on odd too. Also, it's called list, as array in Python is a completely different type.

Comment: Yours is even simpler! Sorry for the "list" vs "array" issue, I just edited it. You can still call `b[1][1]`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `a` is your given list. Then you can invoke these two commands for separate lists:

```
b=[a [i]  for i in range (len (a)) if i % 2==0]
c=[a [i]  for i in range (len (a)) if i % 2==1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
def grouper(iterable,n):
    return zip(*([iter(iterable)]*n))

print grouper(range(9),3)
# [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]

# if len(iterable)%n : truncation
print grouped(range(14),3)
# [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11)]
```